# Get PIDL's of items in GetOpenFileName dialog

Tags: c#, winapi

I have an [implementation](http://svn.cyberduck.ch/trunk/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/winforms/commondialog/SelectFileAndFolderDialog.cs) of `CommonDialog` that allows the user to multi-select files *and* folders. As long as the Explorer setting 'Hide extensions for known file types' is not checked (checked by default) the class works fine. If it's checked (known extensions are not part of the filename anymore) it doesn't work as I get the selected file and folder names directly (`LVM_GETITEMTEXT`)from the listview items.

I've found a [MSDN magazine article](http://svn.cyberduck.ch/trunk/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/winforms/commondialog/SelectFileAndFolderDialog.cs) that describes a solution in C++. The idea is to get the backing PIDL object from the selected items which contain the full filename including the extension independent of the Explorer settings.

Any idea how to port this to C#?

Comment: That code was written in C#, not C++, that porting job was already done.  Hacking the dialog is a Really Bad Idea.  Especially with the later .NET releases moving to the IFileDialog interfaces to get the native Vista and Win7 dialogs.  This is an endlessly moving target.

Comment: Hacking the dialogs will lead to no end of pain. You should find another solution.

Comment: The first link is my existing C# code I'd like to extend with the technique described in the 2nd link. I've the requirement to let the user multi-select files and folders at the same time. I cannot think of any other solution. The only other solution might be to place the ExplorerBrowser component from the [Windows API Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) on a selection form. This comp allows to select both types but it needs Vista at least (I need WinXP compatibility). Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

code to get pidl..

```
lvitem lvi;
lvi.mask = lvif_param; //0x0004;
lvi.iItem = 1;// the index of item u want to get
sendmessage(listviewhandle,LVM_GETITEM,0,ref lvi);

//Now u can get pidl from lvi.lParam member.
```

Comment: OP wants multiple pidls.